# how can i sort this array by age value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

im studying right now and starting with reactjs and all that, i have to make a web page based in Game of thrones using an API, i recieve the api data and i can print in screen the img, name and age of the characters, but i need to sort them by their age.

componentDidMount() {

```
    fetch('https://api.got.show/api/show/characters/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                items: json,
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

}



render() {

    const {items} = this.state;
    

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ul>
                {items.filter(item=> item.age && item.age.age).map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                    <img src={item.image} alt="personajes" ></img>  Name: {item.name} | age: {item.age.age}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );

}
```

}

export default App;

This is what i got till now, i did the filter cause there's some characters that doesnt have known age, well, i guess i have to use a sort, something like

```
items.sort((a,b) => a.item.age.age - b.item.age.age)
```

json item example:

```
0   
titles  […]
origin  […]
siblings    […]
spouse  […]
lovers  []
plod    0
longevity   []
plodB   0
plodC   0
longevityB  []
longevityC  []
culture […]
religion    […]
allegiances […]
seasons []
appearances […]
_id "5cc0757c04e71a0010b86ac3"
name    "Eddard Stark"
slug    "Eddard_Stark"
image   "https://vignette.wikia.n…wn/323?cb=20160730050722"
gender  "male"
alive   false
death   298
father  "Rickard Stark"
house   "House Stark"
first_seen  "Winter Is Coming\""
actor   "Sean Bean"
related […]
createdAt   "2019-04-24T14:41:00.761Z"
updatedAt   "2019-04-24T14:41:00.761Z"
__v 0
pagerank    {…}
age :
name    "Eddard Stark"
age 60
id  "5cc0757c04e71a0010b86ac3"
```

But idk how i have to exactly write it in my code and make it work, i have to make also a button where i can order from minor to major and to the reverse, thanks a lot if you can help me, i ve been with this all day yesterday, and sorry for not a perfect english, hope you can understand everything :P

Comment: Can you please add example data?

Comment: @Rajesh There's some character, for example, Eddard Stark does have 60 years old, Robb Stark 33, so in the page should appears first Robb Stark and so

Comment: Please add a sample of `items` array to the question in a JSON format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you can find more information regarding sorting arrays in javascript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

You can *chain* some Array operations like sort and filter, so the solution would be to first filter out the characters without an age, and then sort the result:

```js
characters.filter(character => character.age).sort(compareFunction);
```

This can then be used inside your JSX to display the characters without an age in order:

```js
return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>
      {items
        .filter(item => item.age && item.age.age)
        .sort((prev, next) => prev.age - next.age)
        .map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.image} alt="personajes" ></img>  Name: {item.name} | age: {item.age.age}
          </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Here is a working example to removing characters without an age and sorting ages in ascending and descending order:

```js
function displayList(list) {
  let html = '';
  for (const person of list) {
    html += `<li>${person.name}: ${person.age || "?"}</li>`;
  }
  document.getElementById('age-list').innerHTML = html;
}

const ageList = [{
    name: "John",
    age: 12
  },
  {
    name: "Tim"
  },
  {
    name: "Steven",
    age: 40
  },
  {
    name: "Marie",
    age: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Amy"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheldon",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Charlotte",
    age: 25
  }
];

displayList(ageList);

document.getElementById('asc').onclick = () => {
  const ascList = ageList.filter(item=> item.age).sort((prev, next) => {
    return prev.age - next.age;
  });
  displayList(ascList);
}

document.getElementById('desc').onclick = () => {
  const ascList = ageList.filter(item=> item.age).sort((prev, next) => {
    return next.age - prev.age;

  });
  displayList(ascList);
}
```

```html
<button id="asc">Ascending</button>
<button id="desc">Descending</button>
<ul id="age-list"></ul>
```

Of course you will have to adapt the dataset and function to your own dataset in order for it to work for you.

Comment: They already know how to sort. `items.sort((a,b) => a.item.age.age - b.item.age.age)` Their issue is *"some characters that doesnt have known age*"

Comment: exactly, i know how to sort, my problem is that in that database there's some characters without age, that's why i used this filter {items.filter(item=> item.age && item.age.age) with that filter all the characters appears and avoid the ones without age, but idk how to insert the sort in the code i already have.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take in account objects without an age property.

Comment: The thing is that i can't print a character without age, so cant be a character printed that doesn't have an age. :S but thanks for this answer.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your problem. You want to filter out characters without an age, and then sort the remaining characters by age?

Comment: I've updated my answer to solve that problem.

Comment: hey, so you are saying i can add a sort inside this? im gonna try, but im really lost right now, idk how exactly do it, i think i'm super blocked right now {items.filter(item=> item.age && item.age.age).map(item => (

Comment: Yes, you can [chain array methods](https://gomakethings.com/chaining-array-methods-in-vanilla-js/). So it should be like this: `charachters.filter.sort.map`. I'm not at my computer at the moment, but when I get back I'll add some more information.

Comment: I have added a react example in my answer

Comment: YES! this worked, that was my problem, didnt know how to exactly write it, thanks A LOT.